# Using lag() for dynamic rows postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table named 'quantity' as below

Table 1 :

```
----------------------------------------------------
Price | A_Quantity | B_Quantity | Remaining_quantity
----------------------------------------------------
30    | 17         | 2          | 0    
32    | 17         | 4          | 0    
33    | 17         | 4          | 0
----------------------------------------------------
```

I want the field - `Remaining_quantity` to be filled as below

Table 2 :

```
----------------------------------------------------
Price | A_Quantity | B_Quantity | Remaining_quantity
----------------------------------------------------
30    | 17         | 2          | 15    
32    | 17         | 4          | 11
33    | 17         | 4          | 7
----------------------------------------------------
```

I have used the below query, but it doesn't give the expected result.

```
update quantity set remaining_quantity = remaining_quantity - 
   (lag(B_Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY price))
```

Comment: Is there any unique id on the table?

Comment: `1+` for well articulated question and your attempt

Answer (score 0):

This is 1 way to do it.

Note: By looking at data, looks like there is no specific primary key, but combination of `price` and `a_quantity` looks unique, hence I used these 2 columns in `join`. If this is just your example data and in actual you do have a `primary key`, I suggest you to change the join condition to that `primary key`.

**<kbd>[REXTESTER DEMO](http://rextester.com/TGOB13839)</kbd>**

```
update Table1
set remaining_quantity = upd_tbl.cum
from 
(
select t.*
,a_quantity - sum(b_quantity) over (partition by a_quantity order by price) as cum
from table1 t
) upd_tbl
where table1.price=upd_tbl.price
and table1.a_quantity=upd_tbl.a_quantity;
```

Explanation:
`sum(b_quantity) over (partition by a_quantity order by price)` will give you `cumulative sum` for a partition (2,6,10..). Now you can subtract it from `a_quantity` to get your output.

Comment: Thank you, It works. The data i have provided was just a sample. I do have a Pk

Comment: Happy to help. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)